# STM32L0-Nucleo, UART linkage doesn't work

Tags: stm32

My task is to send a message from the STM32 to a PC using 2 XBEE cards. In fact I have an STM32 card which is linked to an XBEE card via USART1. I linked TX, RX, VCC (3.3V) and GND of the 2 cards together.

My code just contains..

```cpp
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint16_t*)message, messageSize, 1000);
HAL_Delay(1000);
```

..but it doesn't work. The USART division is not done. When I looked for the radio module in the XCTU software distributed by the XBEE manufacturer it tells me that device is not found.

What must I do?

PS: the 2 cards have a fixed baudrate of 9600 baud.